# Hide sites in Sharepoint page

Tags: site-settings

We have a couple of sites(projects) in our SharePoint portal. However, a lot of them are not used (closed projects). I want to hide them from the display. But we want to give the option to the user to decide which site can be hidden from display, in other words, the user can update some field value and the sites go is hidden. Is this possible?

I tried searching this site, was not able to find anything matching to my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Create a links list for them to access links to the site and add a column that has a check box to toggle the links to appear or not in the main view. (As an alternate solution)